# Run MQTT with 1 connect and multiple concurrent publish

Tags: jmeter, jmx

I am trying to sending multiple publish to a MQTT broker concurrently from Jmeter. What I wanted to implement is as follows

1. 1-MQTT Connect
2. 100-MQTT Publish concurrently
3. 1-MQTT Disconnect.

I tried adding the above 3 in different thread groups, On execution I am getting "Connection not found" in the 2nd Thread group containing the publish part.  I am using a csv data set config for getting the data to be published.

Please let me know if there is any alternative way to simulate the same in jmeter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the above By setting the connection property as a JMeter Property 
So this is what I did, according to my test iterations
1. I created multiple connections numbering equal to the test count
2. Set those connections as property 
3. Created Next thread group that will take all these connections and do MQTT publish concurrently

The property setting I did using BeanPostProcessor

Answer (score 0):

Different [Thread Groups](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) represent different groups of virtual users, they don't have anything in common and not share any context (unless you manually transfer the data using [__setProperty() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty) or [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-inter-thread-communication-plugin-in-jmeter))

So move the [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) under the same Thread Group and everything should start working as you expect.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response but if I add everything in the same thread group then for each publish there is a connect and disconnect. This is not desirable as it is creating overhead. Is it possible to set the MQTT connection to a property and use the same in the next thread group ?